# Deleting a Term from TermStore removes the entire second level navigation

Tags: 2010, term-store, term

We are supporting an intranet site where the second level navigation of the site comes from term store.The problem we are facing is that whenever we are deleting a term(corresponding to second level navigation)from the term store, the entire second level navigation becomes invisible on the home page.
We are not able to figure out what exactly is the cause.
Any help will be highly appreciated.